# Fail to trigger my php script when mail received by my Postfix

Tags: php, email, ubuntu-14.04, postfix-mta

I am in need of serious help.

I am running Postfix mail on ubuntu 14.04.1.

I want to "trigger a PHP script when Postfix server receives a mail" After investigation and the help of many tuto, . I have configured "[postfix](https://thecodingmachine.io/triggering-a-php-script-when-your-postfix-server-receives-a-mail)" & "[Postfix virtual Aliases](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixBasicSetupHowto#Install_Postfix)" first time (I don't have deep knowledge of it) and I wrote my php code but my script output is always empty. Below all necessary file that allow you to detect my error.

**main.cf**

```
 # See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = localhost
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = domain1.com, panawara.org, panawaredev-MS-7788, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
virtual_mailbox_domains = /etc/postfix/vhosts
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmaps
virtual_minimum_uid = 1000
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
```

**master.cf**

```
    #
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================

#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
#submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING

#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup

pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
    -o content_filter=filter:dummy

cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache

smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
        -o content_filter=filter:dummy

#myhook    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=F user=vmail argv=/home/panawaredev/Documents/postfix.php ${sender} ${size} ${recipient}
filter    unix  -    n   n   -   -   pipe
  flags=Rq user=vmail null_sender=
  argv=/home/panawaredev/Documents/postfix.php ${sender} -- ${recipient}    
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

**postfix.php**

```
 #!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$file = fopen("postfixtest", "a");
fwrite($file, "Script successfully ran at ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."\n");


// read from stdin
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email = "first test";
while (!feof($fd)) {
    $line = fread($fd, 1024);
    $email .= $line;
echo ".";
}
echo $email;
fclose($fd);

fwrite($file, $email);
fclose($file);

?>
```

**maillog file**

```
Apr 12 22:43:16 panawaredev-MS-7788 postfix/cleanup[10886]: 4B84620ECC: message-id=<20150412214316.4B84620ECC@localhost>
Apr 12 22:43:16 panawaredev-MS-7788 postfix/bounce[10891]: 3680120ECA: sender non-delivery notification: 4B84620ECC
Apr 12 22:43:16 panawaredev-MS-7788 postfix/qmgr[10293]: 4B84620ECC: from=<>, size=2234, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 12 22:43:16 panawaredev-MS-7788 postfix/qmgr[10293]: 3680120ECA: removed
Apr 12 22:43:16 panawaredev-MS-7788 postfix/local[10892]: 4B84620ECC: to=<panawaredev@panawara.org>, relay=local, delay=0.07, delays=0.03/0/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Apr 12 22:43:16 panawaredev-MS-7788 postfix/qmgr[10293]: 4B84620ECC: removed
```

Is this the correct way to " Trigger a PHP script when your Postfix server receives a mail " ? I

If Yes , can you help me to run my script else any advice to find another way.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the configuration above are correct and also the 2 tutoriels mentionned above are very useful. HOPE THAT THEY CAN BE HELPFUL FOR SOMEONE ELSE.

The problems was caused by the permission in ubuntu.

I used "sudo":

```
sudo mail -s "hello" -a /path/file.dat info@domain1.com
content of my email is here
.
cc:
```

Then the script runned.